# Can Signal have zero recipients in BPMN?

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda, camunda-modeler

I've read the camunda doc, but I don't find anything about it.
I know it doesn't make sense throw something that nobody will catch, but is it possible?

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.7/reference/bpmn20/events/signal-events/

https://camunda.com/bpmn/reference/#events-signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can model a throwing signal event when there are no receivers. The event will simply throw the signal and continue the normal flow (without anyone ever using the event).

In contrary to that, the catching signal events can not be used without a throwing signal event. If you use a catching signal event without a throwing signal event the process will stop at this event and will never be able to continue.

Comment: The statement about catching may be correct for Camunda, but is not correct for BPMN as you can have ad hoc listeners and interrupting listeners that never fire but don’t block.

Comment: Remember also that the receptors must exist before the singal is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

In the `Business Process Model And Notation 2.0` specification(can be found at

https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/), P253, in the `Table 10.89 - Intermediate Event Types in Normal Flow`:

> (Signal) This type of Event is used for sending or receiving Signals. A Signal is
>   for general communication within and across Process levels, across
>   Pools, and between Business Process Diagrams. A BPMN Signal is
>   similar to a signal flare that shot into the sky for anyone who might be
>   interested to notice and then react. Thus, there is a source of the Signal,
>   but no specific intended target.

Hope that helps.